# Google Dataflow - parallelize JDBC to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are using the Google provided batch template JDBC to Bigquery to load a number of tables from PostgreSQL to BigQuery.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#jdbctobigquery

Is there a way to run multiple template jobs simultaneously? In our current set up, each job spins up worker instances and takes several minutes, while the actual work takes only a few seconds.

Wondering if there are more efficient approaches in simple data transfer from a relational database to BigQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: Dataflow, like Compute Engines, can take up to two minutes to instanciate itself. Have you tried launching multiple Template Jobs ? It should work. Also, you should consider implementing your own Beam code to connect to your DB with Dataflow.

Comment: Yes, I am launching multiple of them. I'd like to build my own Beam code, but not sure where to start. Where would you suggest I look? Thanks for responding!

Comment: You can find corresponding code of Template [on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java) and you should have a look at [Beams's examples](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/)